# firebase.uid vs. facebook.id

Tags: json, authentication, firebase

Firebase login returns a data object containing a `uid` in the form of `facebook:888888888888888` but I don't like the `facebook` prefix, neither the `:` character in between.

In the same object (in a deeper branch), facebook itself returns an `id` in the form of `888888888888888`. Both happen to be the same number.

`// example:
{
  "uid": "facebook:888888888888888",
  "facebook": {
    "id": "888888888888888"
  }
}`

**Is the `888888888888888` integer still unique so that I can use it as a userID in my application?**

I'm using exclusively facebook login for authorization.

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to treat the uid as a random string. Those two values are equal now, but in the future user ids may be anything, as long as that thing is unique for your app.

Comment: Vague comment. What do you mean “treat as random”? How do you “treat as random”? What do you mean “user ids”, you mean `uid`, or `facebook:id`? I'm creating the app right now so anything is potentially unique to my app.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. Currently, Firebase authentication gives you a `uid` in the format of `<provider>:<id>`, and this is the basis of a unique id for your app. However, it is *very likely* that this format will change, and become a random string. As a result, I would very much caution against parsing the `id` out of the `uid` and using this as a core component of your app, because your app would break if new users were given new id formats (existing users will always have the same format).